# Preprocessing Macro

Tags: c++, c

if in the beginning of my file i do

```
#define dbg_kprintf \
   if (x_var) kprintf
```

I late on do statements using

```
dbg_kprintf ("blablabla");
```

My question is that will dbg_kprintf be only defined if xvar is defined somewhere else? If it is not then will dbg_kprintf statements not be used at compile time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in that example, x_var has to exist somewhere or it will fail to compile.  You are looking for something like

```
#if (x_var)
  #define dbg_kprintf kprintf
#else
  #define dbg_kprintf
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

No, that will either compile into a run-time check of the variable, or nothing (if the variable is in fact compile-time constant with a false value and the optimizer feels like eliminating the dead code) or a call always (if it's a compile-time constant with a true value). So, now you know.

The typical way to ensure that debug code is excluded from non-debugging builds is to use a preprocessor symbol to guard the code. Note that it might require you to manage the arguments differently.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ Macros can take arguments. It will be defined either way, as it's just a pre-processing directive but the compile will fail if it's not defined. To pass an argument to a macro use this syntax

```
#define foo(X)  ((X))
```

Answer (score 0):

`dbg_kprintf` will be used *before* complie time. The preprocessor will substitute in its place the contents you defined: `if (x_var) kprintf`. Then it will try to compile your code normally.